# Can you deck out?

Tags: scrolls

Is it possible to run out of cards in Scrolls? I don't see a deck count or anything during battle so I wasn't sure if it was something that I should keep in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.

I was under the assumption that yes, you should be able to deck out but that assumption was corrected on the last game I played.  While trying to figure out the best strategy for Order when playing against an opponent with a board filled with lobbers, I found that I could actually "bank" cards in my hand because lobbers don't hurt your totems.

I never found a good strategy but I did notice that my single, Honorable General appeared twice in my hand.  First, near the beginning of the game before I started banking and much later, after I had cycled through more than the 50 cards in my deck.

Comment: As a follow-up comment.  I didn't have time to try this last night, but this makes me wonder if you could create a small, powerful deck of, say, 10 cards.  I wonder if you can deck out IF all of your cards are in play (in your hand or on the board.)  If you can't, then you could have a deck of nothing but 3-4 exceptional rares and do some exceptional damage.

Comment: There's a minimum deck size, possibly 40 cards. I can check this once I get home.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good idea to keep your deck at minimum size to maximise the chance to get your prefered cards/combos. Minimum size is 50 though.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't run out of scrolls.

At the start of a game all your scrolls are in your deck (a.k.a. the *library*). After scrolls are drawn or sacrificed they end up in the *graveyard*. When there are no more scrolls to draw from the library, the graveyard is shuffled and reused as a new library.

This is described in the [wiki](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Library_and_Graveyard).